# Найти индекс минимального значения (но больше нуля) - результата деления столбцов в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

Необходимо с помощью python в dataframe (таблица в excel):

1. Разделить значения одного столбца на значение другого столбца
2. Определить строку с минимальным значением после деления, но больше нуля.
3. Вывести наименование строки с минимальным значением.

   ```
               РАС Норма
   Абакан         0    3
   Альметьевск 3391    2
   Анапа       5229    5
   Ангарск     1421    3
   Арзамас     4106    11
   Армавир     4979    0
   ```

Использую pandas

1. `df['РАС']/df['Норма']`
2. `min(df['РАС']/df['Норма'])` выводит 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask = df['РАС'] != 0

res = df.loc[[(df.loc[mask,'РАС'] / df.loc[mask,'Норма']).idxmin()]]
```

Результат:

```
In [126]: res
Out[126]:
          РАС  Норма
Арзамас  4106     11
```

чтобы вывести только индекс:

```
In [130]: (df.loc[mask,'РАС'] / df.loc[mask,'Норма']).idxmin()
Out[130]: 'Арзамас'
```

Comment: @РусланРаимов: [вживую можно попробовать](https://repl.it/@zed1/pandas-nonzero-min-after-division)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо! не знал о таком сервисе...