# Индекс минимального значения (исключая строку) - результата деления столбцов в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо найти индекс минимального значения - результата деления столбцов в DataFrame исключая результат деления столбцов в определенной строке.

Пример:

Столбцы: a, b, c. Строки: 1, 2, 3. Необходимо отобрать минимальное значение в результате деления "a" на "b", исключая ноль и при этом исключая результаты деления в строке 3

Comment: чем этот вопрос отличается от [того, что вы задавали ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798228/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be)?

Comment: ранее вопрос - необходимо было исключить только 0. А теперь вопрос об исключении результатов строки. Пример: Столбцы: a, b, c. Строки: 1, 2, 3. Необходимо отобрать минимальное значение в результате деления "a" на "b", исключая ноль и при этом исключая результаты деления в строке 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [266]: df
Out[266]:
              РАС  Норма
Абакан          0      3
Альметьевск  3391      2
Анапа        5229      5
Ангарск      1421      3
Арзамас      4106     11
Армавир      4979      0

In [267]: mask = (df['РАС'] != 0) & ~df.index.isin(['Армавир','Арзамас'])

In [268]: res = df.loc[[(df.loc[mask,'РАС'] / df.loc[mask,'Норма']).idxmin()]]

In [269]: res
Out[269]:
          РАС  Норма
Ангарск  1421      3
```

Пошагово:

```
In [276]: mask
Out[276]:
Абакан         False
Альметьевск     True
Анапа           True
Ангарск         True
Арзамас        False
Армавир        False
Name: РАС, dtype: bool

In [277]: df.loc[mask]
Out[277]:
              РАС  Норма
Альметьевск  3391      2
Анапа        5229      5
Ангарск      1421      3

In [278]: df.loc[mask,'РАС'] / df.loc[mask,'Норма']
Out[278]:
Альметьевск    1695.500000
Анапа          1045.800000
Ангарск         473.666667
dtype: float64

In [279]: (df.loc[mask,'РАС'] / df.loc[mask,'Норма']).idxmin()
Out[279]: 'Ангарск'
```